# Mapreduce - Heap memory issue while processing large xml file

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I have used Mahout XMLINPUTFORMAT in my MR code and XML(small size) is processed successfull.

**Now, when am trying to send 800MB of input XML file am getting Java Heap memory exception, it's been getting after strong textmap has been processed to 83% and job got failed**.

I have tried with below configurations even though no luck on process.

Could anyone please let me know how process large(huge) data xml file?

"

```
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize","3073741824")                                       
conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Xmx14096m -Xss2048m")                                 
conf.set("mapreduce.map.child.java.opts", "-Xmx8072m")                                       
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx3024m")                                 
conf.setInt("io.sort.factor",15 )                      
conf.setInt("mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb",2048 )                    
conf.set("mapreduce.task.timeout","6000000")                             
conf.set("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", "3072")                                     
conf.set("mapreduce.map.java.opts", "-Xmx3072m")                                         
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", "1024")                                         
conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.java.opts", "-Xmx1024m")                                           
conf.set("task.io.sort.mb", "2048")                                            
conf.set("task.io.sort.factor", "100")                                              
conf.set("mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent","0.40")
```

Comment: what's your default block size?

Comment: @ almas shaikh  128 MB default block size

Comment: which Hadoop version?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem in your configuration.

First, you don't need the `mapred.child.java.opts` or the `mapreduce.(map|reduce).child.java.opts` settings.
Second, you want the heap space set in `mapreduce.(map|reduce).java.opts` to be 80% of the `mapreduce.(map|reduce).memory.mb`

If after making these changes, you're still facing the heap space problem, I'd recommend either processing smaller splits or raising the heap space for the tasks.

Comment: Can you post the logs from one of the failed tasks and the MrApplicationMaster logs? Also, you'll probably get quicker responses on the Hadoop User Mailing List.

Comment: Hello Sagar, Can you please explain how you solved this issue?